# Reference Azure Table Storage into a Portable Class Library (PCL)

Tags: c#, azure-storage, nuget-package, portable-class-library

I've just created a portable class library that used the [Azure Table storage v7.0.1-preview](http://Azure%20Table%20storage%20v7.0.1-preview).

And I have some problem making this works properly. The code below throw an exception (`TypeLoadException`):

```
 var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
 var cloudTable = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(settingsTableName);
 var seg = await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery(), null);
 return seg.Results;
```

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuerySegment' from assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I've created a portable class library :

[image: Create a portable class library using visual studio 2015]

I've added a reference to the WindowsAzure.Storage v7.0.1-preview:

```
Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 7.0.1-preview
```

[image: Add WindowsAzure.Storage v7.0.1 preview using Nuget Package Manager Console]

So to reproduce the problem, I've got a single class in this library:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

public class AzureTableUtilitiy
{
    public static async Task<IList<DynamicTableEntity>> RetrieveAsync(string connectionString, string settingsTableName)
    {
        var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var cloudTable = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(settingsTableName);
        var seg = await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery(), null);
        return seg.Results;
    }
}
```

And I just wanted to test it ... using a console app (named AzureTableStorageTest) => I've added a reference to `WindowsAzure.Storage v7.0.1-preview` also in this project.

The Console App has a reference to the Portable CLass Library.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = AzureTableUtilitiy.RetrieveAsync(
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageAccountConnectionstring"].ConnectionString,
         "ExternalSettingsStore").Result;
    }
}
```

So the code above throw the exception. But If I execute the code directly from the console app, every thing work fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageAccountConnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
        var cloudTable = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference("ExternalSettingsStore");
        var seg = cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery(), null).Result;
        var result = seg.Results;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me what I am missing ^^ ?

**EDIT : Details of the exception:**

A System.TypeLoadException is thrown.

- Message: Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuerySegment' from assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
- StackTrace:

  at AzureTableStorageUtility.AzureTableUtilitiy.RetrieveAsync(String connectionString, String settingsTableName)

  at AzureTableStorageTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\AzureTableStorageTest\AzureTableStorageTest2\Program.cs:line 24

**EDIT**

this is a sample app that reproduce the issue :

- https://github.com/CrazyTuna/azure-table-storage-pcl

Comment: What exception are you getting? The exception/stack trace would give us more insight here.

Comment: @jehine-MSFT, I've updated the stack trace. Do you want me to create a github repo for you to run the app ?

Comment: Dumb question: @Thomas, did you include the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table as well as Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage? I believe you need them both

Comment: @jehine-MSFT, yes sure. here is my test project: https://github.com/CrazyTuna/azure-table-storage-pcl. Thanks^^

Comment: @jehine-MSFT any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a shot in the dark here, but could you try changing the value of "Copy Local" in your PCL's Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage reference to true.

Here's an article that talks about this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2013/01/09/how-to-resolve-the-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-issues-on-windows-azure-web-sites/